# User login not working unknown error

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, authentication

i don't know what's wrong with my login script. It keeps saying invalid username or password. But in my eyes, everything is set as it should be.

**PHP5:**

```
<?php require ('../lib/config.php'); ?>
<?php

ob_start();
$tbl_name='users';
$user_name='Username';
$pass_name='Password';
$salt='';

mysql_connect("$cchost", "$ccuser", "$ccpass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$ccname")or die("cannot select DB");

$username=str_replace(' ','_', $myusername); 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
$password=hash('whirlpool', $mypassword);

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $user_name='$username' and $pass_name='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$donator=$row['donator'];
$player=$row['player'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($donator == '1') {
session_register("donator"); 
}
if ($player == '1') {
session_register("player"); 
}
if($count==1){
session_register("username");
header("Location: index_ucp.php");
}
else {
header("Location: login_ucp.php?err=1");
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**HTML Form:**

```
<div class="login">
      <form method="post" name="frmLogin" class="well form-inline" action="dologin.php">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Username">
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input-medium" placeholder="Password">
        <button name="btnLogin" type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

I'm trying for hours and hours to fix it, but i can't. You all are my last hope.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check if value isset `isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"]` and same for password

Comment: Sidenote: From the manual for [`session_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) **Warning**
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @karthikr Ive did it, with an error msg if not. now testing.. - Nothing, it still says invalid username and password.

Comment: according to this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php your hash will return a field of 128 characters. Make sure your database destination field is big enough, or else it gets truncated and you won't get a match

Comment: @D.M. can you echo `$sql` variable what it prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have these two lines in the wrong order:

```
$username=str_replace(' ','_', $myusername); 
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
```

Later code will be using `$username` which won't have been initialised properly

Comment: You have a point there. However, I hope the OP isn't anticipating on people who enter a space in there. What risks in happening is that if let's say, someone enters "Peter Piper", that would be changed to "Peter_Piper". If the username is "PeterPiper", then there will be no match. What I think the OP should be using is `trim()`, but I'm just making a very wild guess.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to expect a user to enter their username correctly. There's only so many variations one can account for.

Comment: True. I'm just wondering why the OP's using `str_replace()` in the first place.

Comment: @MikeW That the ordering failed is true, but 90% of the users are already registered somewhere else and they all have a _ in their name. They are used to type it without an underscore. str_replace only replaces every space into an underscore. Out of expierence i know that usernames without an underscore also could login. Anyways, Fred said that the function session_register is dead. What shall i use now?

Comment: You can simpy assign values to the `$_SESSION` array instead. E.g. `session_register('username')` is equivalent to `$_SESSION['username']`. You should take a look at the reference [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)

Comment: Ive used $_SESSION before, i thought session_register was a similiar version to it.. it was the old like i see. That would be `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is, some how not setting the session. `http://ryk.us/login` Username: `Whirl Pool`   Password: `123456789`
I have debugged temp the `username   donator   player` it has to shown `Whirl_Pool   0   1`. but it doesn't, like it is getting thrown back to the login page because the destinated page couldn't detect any sign of `$_SESSION['username'] ` How could that happen?

Comment: Please take a good look at the PHP reference for session variables. You probably need `session_start()` at the top of your pages but you're really into a different question now.